# Does Thorns damage trigger Area Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

Will Thorns damage trigger the Area Damage effect?

If an enemy hits me and takes Thorns damage, does it have a chance to trigger the Area Damage on the creature that took the Thorns damage?

Comment: I removed the backticks as per [this meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/using-code-ticks-for-technical-term-highlighting-considered-harmful).

Comment: do you mean the "chance area damage on hit" type of buff on weapons?

Comment: @horatio Yes, this is about such bonus. It is not exclusive to weapons, though, and it all adds up to a value in Character Details called Area Damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the extensive testing and research done for [this article](http://bannedofgamers.com/index.php?AD/), it states that:

> AD cannot be procced from thorns damage.

[This article](http://bannedofgamers.com/index.php?AD/) was also advertised on the official Diablo 3 website.

Comment: Good find! Your answer blows mine away.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't give you a definitive answer, from research and the internet it would appear that it does not. Look at [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12426382759) on the D3 forums. To sum up: You can't proc from a proc.